# How to break javascript object reference

Tags: javascript, object, reference

Consider below code

```
var obj={a:1,b:2};
var copiedObj=obj;
obj.a=3;
console.log(copiedObj.a); // 3
```

The question here is how can I change the values of obj without changing the values in copiedObj;

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make a shallow copy of an object, you can use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
const obj = {a:1,b:2};
const copiedObj = Object.assign({}, obj);
obj.a=3;
console.log(copiedObj.a); // 1
```

Note that this is only a shallow copy though, so if you have a deeply nested object, those nested references can still be the same. For example:

```js
const obj = {
  a: {
    a: 1
  },
  b:2
};
var copiedObj = Object.assign({}, obj);
obj.a.a=3;
console.log(copiedObj.a.a); // 3
```

---

As an alternative to Object.assign, if you're using babel's [transform-object-rest-spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread.html) transpiler (or if you're using a browser that supports it natively), you can do the same thing like this:

```js
const obj = {a: 1, b: 2};
const copiedObj = {...obj};
obj.a = 3;
console.log(copiedObj.a); //1
```